# Programatically create folders with names based on values

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, directory

I need to create 10.000 folders named `a0_value`, where value is read from a `.txt` file.

The `.txt` file is arranged on 2 columns. It has exactly 10.000 lines.

value is always extracted from the 2nd column.

So the first folder would be named `a0_value1`, where value1 is the first value of second column in the `.txt` file and so on.

I want to do this in a `bash` script.
I never wrote such a script.

I understand `cd`, `mkdir` and that `$` gets the value of a variable. I know I need to write `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script.

Please, can you help me do this?

The bash version is > (bigger than) 4.0.
Thank you!

Comment: Anything you have tried? Hints: research on `while read value`-type of loops and how you want to extract the second column. Always add an example input file to questions.

Comment: Thanks, working on it with the awk command in a for i in {1..10000} loop. I will read into those commands as well, thanks!

Comment: Loop through the file instead of using a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, contents of `file.txt` is something like

```
abcde  12345
abc    5a3bg2
gdrr   something
```

etc., and you want to create folders `a0_12345`, `a0_5a3bg2`, `a0_something` etc.

So I would use:

```
awk '{ print "mkdir a0_" $2 }' file.txt | bash
```

It doesn't even have to be in a script, if you need to do this only once. Just type the above on the command line.

**Note**: of course this assumes that there are **NO** spaces anywhere in either of the columns of `file.txt`, and there are **NO** "special" characters that may cause trouble to the shell, like `'`, `"`, `?`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `&` etc. in the values that are to be folder names.

Comment: no spaces, no special values. many thanks!